# A question about positive Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $F$ be a set of reals of positive Lebesgue measure .  Does there exist a countable $Q$,$F+Q$ almost cover $R$ in the sense of measure.

Comment: What about $F=[0,1]$ and $Q=\mathbb Q$?

Comment: $F$ might be a nowhere dense set.

Comment: I can't. answer the question. it's as difficult  as the oringal question for me.

Comment: Hint: Lebesgue density theorem.

Comment: choose an $x\in F$ with density 1 , and so on?

Comment: Yes, choose $x \in F$ with density $1$, let $Q = \mathbb Q$, and show $F+Q$ has full measure.  Can you do that?